# Can't send a value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I can't add a value in time table in which is the foreign key is id from info table.

**add_time.php**

```
<?php
     $time_id = $_GET['id'];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM time WHERE id = '$time_id'";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<form action="insert_time.php?=<?php echo "$time_id"; ?>" method="POST">
    min: <input type="text" name="min"/><br/>
</form>
```

**insert_time.php**

```
$min = $_POST['min'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO time (min) VALUES ($min)
SELECT id FROM info WHERE info.id = time.id";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
```

**info table**

```
| id | name |
| 1  | jose |
```

**time table**

```
| time_id | id | min |
|   1     |  1 |  2  |
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO time (min) VALUES ($min)
```

you either need to add the additional column "time_id"  or "id" (whichever is not auto-incrementing), to you insert statement.

ALternatively, you need to update a specific record with the $min (but you need an update statement for that obviously).

Comment: sir excuse me im just a newbie but can you please make it into a code? so that i can understand it more sir?